# Static linking of Protocol Buffers results in conflicts with existing symbols

Tags: c++, linux, protocol-buffers, onnx

We are trying to implement a Protocol Buffers format (ONNX) importer for a C++ runtime. Our runtime will be used by frontend applications, which also use the Protocol Buffers models.

When trying to execute a process which runs both frontend and backend components, we are seeing errors indicating that a symbol name `conflicts with the existing symbol`.

```
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:109] Symbol name "onnx.AttributeProto" conflicts with the existing symbol "onnx.AttributeProto".
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1164] CHECK failed: generated_database_->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size):
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
 what():  CHECK failed: generated_database_->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is there any way to have two components (application and shared object) statically linked PB message handling code and register the same Protobuf symbols in one process? Is there a way to tell the other component not to re-register the  PB messages?

Answer (score 0):

#### Namespace mangling solution

Protocol Buffers holds a global registry based on the `.proto` filename. When 2 pieces of software try to add the same PB message to this registry, you get a name conflict.

One way to work around this is to artificially change the PB Message namespace. You can define a different namespace for your PB message and rely on CMakefile to do the symbol replacement and renaming.

Here is an example from the `onnx-tensorrt` project:

https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorrt/blob/fa0964e8477fc004ee2f49ee77ffce0bf7f711a9/CMakeLists.txt#L92-L97

Answer (score 0):

#### Linking Protocol Buffers statically

Protocol Buffers holds a global registry based on the `.proto` filename. When 2 pieces of software try to add the same PB message to this registry, you get a name conflict.

One way to work around this is to link the entire Protocol Buffers library to your project statically. This effectively creates a separate registry in which PB messages can be registered.

Here is an example from the `ngraph` project:

https://github.com/NervanaSystems/ngraph/commit/3d664abd7b8cc8295b6da79689f9bf119d55a2dd